# Remove "Unique ID" from app.js in Vue production build

Tags: vuejs3, npm-build

Whenever i build a Vue app for production, it adds a unique id to each file built, like this:

```
<script defer="defer" src="/js/app.ee533abb.js"></script>
```

I do understand why this is done, however i am building this particular application for a ESP32 webserver which makes usage of this difficult due to the fact it does not give reply based on a folder, but instructions given in code. So for each new file, have to edit my ESP32 code and upload it again.

Is it possible to stop adding unique id on these files during production build? So that app.js is served as app.js not app.ee533abb.js

```
<script defer="defer" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: How is your build config? Looks like you want to set to false  the filenameHashing

Comment: Yeah, that was the exact function i was looking for :-)